# Spring jpa many to many lazy delete

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring jpa and mysql, I'm having problems with deleting entities, how to do it in the best way?

My Entity user :

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinTable(name = "users_tasks",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "task_id")})
private List<Task> tasks;
```

My Entity task :

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tasks")
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

delete user in userServiceImpl (I'm not sure if this is correct but it works):

```
user.setTasks(Collections.emptyList());
userRepository.save(user);
userRepository.delete(user);
```

delete task in taskServiceImpl (it does not work):

```
task.setUsers(Collections.emptyList());
taskRepository.save(task);
taskRepository.delete(task);
```

exception:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`users_tasks`, CONSTRAINT `FK7todmyl52eiddpi6hc2nfgvbs` FOREIGN KEY (`task_id`) REFERENCES `tasks` (`task_id`))
```

my jpa config:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();    
dataSource.setDriverClassName(
env.getRequiredProperty("database.driver");
dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("database.url"));
dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("database.password"));
dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("database.username"));
return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.taskmanager");
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) {
    DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
    return initializer;
}

private Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans",
            env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans"));
    return properties;
}

private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript(dataScript);
    return populator;
}
```

Help me find the best workaround for removal, are my settings correctly spelled? Thank you

Comment: Why would you *ever* want to cascade remove a `@ManyToMany` association?

Comment: One task may be for several users, but if the task is only for one user and if the user is deleted then the task will be unavailable to anyone and it should be deleted

Comment: ...which means you can never rely on cascade remove to do its job, you always need to remove stuff manually

Comment: I wrote in the question that I'm not sure that this is the best solution, can you offer the right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the table `User` is the owner of the relationship, that's why when updating a user's tasks Hibernate deletes the list of tasks.

One work around to this is to make both entities as the owners of the relationship by setting a join table on the task entity :

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "users_tasks",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "task_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

Please notice that the inverse cloumns are reversed ,the mapped by is removed and the table name is the same.

Another workaround ,which is worth to mention, is  to manage the cascade directly on your Database by altering the `users_tasks` fks using `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: @alexuio can you mark it as an answer then , it is the tick under the vote section on my answer